# Concept of subclassing in JS without using class

Tags: javascript

I am looking to learn about class inheritance and how it may be emulated without using the `class` keyword. It's just an academic/learning exercise.

Does the following method work for doing class inheritance, or am I missing some core concepts?

```js
function Person(name, age) {
    let person = Object.create(Person.prototype);
    person.name = name;
    person.age = age;
    return person;
}
Person.prototype.get_birth_year = function() {
    console.log(new Date().getFullYear() - this.age);
}


function Kid(name, age, dad, mom) {
    let kid = Object.create(Person.prototype);
    kid.dad = dad;
    kid.mom = mom;
    for (let key in Kid.prototype) {
        kid[key] = Kid.prototype[key];
    }
    return kid;
}
Kid.prototype.callMom = function() {
    console.log(`MOM!!! (${this.mom})`);
}


function KidToy(name, age, dad, mom, toyname) {
    let toy = Object.create(Kid.prototype);
    toy.toyname = toyname;
    for (let key in KidToy.prototype) {
        toy[key] = KidToy.prototype[key];
    }
    return toy;
}
KidToy.prototype.findToy = function() {
    console.log('Looking to find the', this.toyname);
}

let p = Person('Bob', 33);
p.get_birth_year();
let k = Kid('Billy', 12, 'Bob', 'Margot');
k.callMom();
let t = KidToy('Billy', 12, 'Bob', 'Margot', 'Potatohead');
t.findToy();
```

The only things I'm doing here to subclass are:

- Create an object with the parent prototype.
- Iterate through the current prototype and tack on those properties to the object.

Or, am I missing some things?

Comment: No exactly. You're missing the prototype chain by doing that. In Javascript the child class instance has access to the parent prototype. There is a known pattern that covers prototype chain that mimics class inheritance out there which I suggest you to use.

Comment: This is not subclassing. Instances of subclasses would inherit in real time, at the moment of a member access.

Comment: You're missing `Kid.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`

Comment: @JonasWilms I see. How would I initialize the parent variables then, such as if doing `super(name, age)`?

Comment: Can you explain in your post _why_ you're trying to do this? Because it's pretty unusual to need to do this in modern JS, and future visitors to the site greatly benefit from seeing why a particular question is being asked, so they can determine whether they should pursue the same strategy and follow any posted/accepted answers, or whether their circumstances are different and they should do things "the conventional way" instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans updated the question.

Comment: You can't properly emulate `super` calls, that's why `class` has a lot of new machinery under the hood to make exactly that possible. With using proper constructor functions (called with `new Kid`, writing to `this`) one can get pretty close with `SuperClass.call(this);`

Comment: Looks like there might be some mild term confusion: while modern JS has class syntax, the only inheritance model is has is prototype inheritance, not the kind of class inheritance that you see in Java/C++/etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain is an excellent writeup about this and covers pretty much exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: If you want to see how it's emulated, then a good way might be to play with babel.io  repl,.  https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=ie%20%3E%3D%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=FAYwNghgzlAEAqBTKAXWBvYtYuWgFAJQYC-wZokMsAygK4BGsiAHrgHYAmcSqGWOPLCL9s2KHQAOiAE4A6XKiIBuAWRJA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.16.12&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D

Comment: See https://levelup.gitconnected.com/prototypal-inheritance-the-big-secret-behind-classes-in-javascript-e7368e76e92a in the section titled **Inheritance using constructors**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. There are three approaches to prototypal inheritance in JS:

1. Using the `new` keyword with a function that acts as a constructor, and assigning methods to that function's `.prototype` so they are inherited by the instances created by it.
2. Using the `Object.create` function to manually create objects that inherit from others.
3. Using the `class`, `constructor` and `super` syntax to write classical-style code in JS. JS classes can only be instantiated with the `new` keyword and support some unique features, though they still use prototypal inheritance underneath.

When you call a function with the `new` keyword, it automatically creates an object that inherits from the function's `.prototype` and exposes it as `this` within the function body.

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

const john = new Person("John", 42);
```

You don't need to create the instance and return it, this is all done by the `new` keyword. Objects like `john` above will have access to all properties stored in `Person.prototype` that aren't shadowed by properties assigned to `john` itself.

`Person.prototype` is itself an object that was created automagically when the `Person` function was defined. It inherits from `Object` and it has one property, `constructor`, which points back to the `Person` function.

---

A few more corrections about your assumptions:

```
let kid = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

With this code, `kid` does not inherit from `Kid.prototype`.

```
for (let key in Kid.prototype) {
    kid[key] = Kid.prototype[key];
}
```

This code copies all the **enumerable** properties of `Kid.prototype` into `kid` at the time of creation. This means that if you ever add properties to `Kid.prototype` later, they won't be in kid`. If` kid`actually inherited from`Kid.prototype`, methods could be added to` Kid.prototype` even after a kid instance was created, and that instance would inherit those methods.

Instead, you probably wanted something like this:

```
function Kid(name, age, dad, mom) {
    // invoke super constructor
    Person.call(this, name, age);

    this.dad = dad;
    this.mom = mom;
}

// Kid extends Person
Kid.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Kid.prototype.constructor = Kid;
```

All kid instances created after this code will inherit not from the default `Kid.prototype` which itself inherits from `Object`, but from our custom-made `Kid.prototype` which inherits from `Person.prototype`.

As you can see, this isn't very intuitive or practical, which is why `class` syntax was added to the language.

Hopefully this gives you a push in the right direction. I personally rarely use inheritance in my own code, and instead adopt a more FP approach with closures and composition.